# Issues with an object- Will not map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

Whenever I run my React program, I receive the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {mappedCats}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in choicesList (at App.js:33)
```

What I am trying to do is take the FEATURES object, iterate through it and create a div for each category. Then iterate through the items of that category to show the name and cost of each item. I tried converting the object to an array, but it doesn't seem to be working. Originally I tried splitting this up into multiple components but I think I was overly ambitious.

The Categories component just takes the props and puts them into a div and paragraphs.

If somebody could point out my mistake I would appreciate it. Thank You

```
import React from 'react'
import Categories from './categories'

const choicesList = (props) => {

  const FEATURES = {
    Processor: [
      {
        name: '17th Generation Intel Core HB (7 Core with donut spare)',
        cost: 700
      },
      {
        name: 'Professor X AMD Fire Breather with sidewinder technology',
        cost: 1200
      }
    ],
    "Operating System": [
      {
        name: 'Ubuntu Linux 16.04',
        cost: 200
      },
      {
        name: 'Bodhi Linux',
        cost: 300
      }
    ],
    "Video Card": [
      {
        name: 'Toyota Corolla 1.5v',
        cost: 1150.98
      },
      {
        name: 'Mind mild breeze 2000',
        cost: 1345
      }
    ],
    Display: [
      {
        name: '15.6" UHD (3840 x 2160) 60Hz Bright Lights and Knobs',
        cost: 1500
      },
      {
        name: '15.3" HGTV (3840 x 2160) Home makeover edition',
        cost: 1400
      },
    ]
  };
  
  
  
    const mappedCats = Object.keys(FEATURES).map((cat) => {
          
          return (

            <div>
              <h1>{cat}</h1>
              {Object.keys(FEATURES[cat]).map((item, idx) => {
                
                return (
                  <Categories  name={FEATURES[cat][idx].name} cost={FEATURES[cat][idx].cost}/>
                  )
              })}
            </div>
          )
          
          
        
  })

  
  return( 
    
    {mappedCats}
    
  )
}

export default choicesList
```

Answer (score 0):

Because React components must render a single root element, you'd need to wrap it in either a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) or an element:

```
return (
  <>{ mappedCats }</>
)
```

As raw js (not enclosed in markup) your render method is returning an object literal:

```js
// this is shorthand for { mappedCats: mappedCats }
return { mappedCats };
```

Answer (score 0):

`mappedCats` itself is a valid element(s). Just return that

`return mappedCats`

```js
const ChoicesList = (props) => {
  const FEATURES = {
    Processor: [
      {
        name: "17th Generation Intel Core HB (7 Core with donut spare)",
        cost: 700,
      },
      {
        name: "Professor X AMD Fire Breather with sidewinder technology",
        cost: 1200,
      },
    ],
    "Operating System": [
      {
        name: "Ubuntu Linux 16.04",
        cost: 200,
      },
      {
        name: "Bodhi Linux",
        cost: 300,
      },
    ],
    "Video Card": [
      {
        name: "Toyota Corolla 1.5v",
        cost: 1150.98,
      },
      {
        name: "Mind mild breeze 2000",
        cost: 1345,
      },
    ],
    Display: [
      {
        name: '15.6" UHD (3840 x 2160) 60Hz Bright Lights and Knobs',
        cost: 1500,
      },
      {
        name: '15.3" HGTV (3840 x 2160) Home makeover edition',
        cost: 1400,
      },
    ],
  };

  const mappedCats = Object.keys(FEATURES).map((cat) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{cat}</h1>
        {Object.keys(FEATURES[cat]).map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {`name: ${FEATURES[cat][idx].name}`}
              <br></br>
              {`cost: ${FEATURES[cat][idx].cost}`}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return mappedCats;
  //return (<div>{ mappedCats }</div>);
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<ChoicesList />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app"> </div>
```